# MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException : Timeout waiting for response

Tags: testing, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-webapi, integration-testing, masstransit

I have 2 micro services that send request from micro A to micro B to get response and my application working perfect,
I wrote a integration test for micro A that when reach to **IRequestCilent** return time out.
**Note:** I can't access to my consumer in micro B in integration test of micro A because of micro B dependencies.
I use masstransit V8 with rabbitmq.

Request message

```
public class GetCurrencyByNameRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Response message

```
public class GetCurrencyByNameResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Command handler in micro A

```
public class CreatePackageAdminCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreatePackageAdminCommand, string>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IRequestClient<GetCurrencyByNameRequest> _client;

    public CreatePackageAdminCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork uow,  IRequestClient<GetCurrencyByNameRequest> client)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<string> Handle(CreatePackageAdminCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // time here out!
        var currency = await _client.GetResponse<GetCurrencyByNameResponse>(new GetCurrencyByNameRequest
        {
            Name = request.CurrencyName
        }, cancellationToken);
        if (currency.Message.Id == null) throw new NotFoundException("CurrencyName Not Valid");

        var package = new Package
        {
            CurrencyName = currency.Message.Name,
            IsActive = request.IsActive,
            IsPromote = request.IsPromote,
            PackageType = request.PackageType,
            Price = request.Price,
            Sort = request.Sort,
            TranslationDescription = new Translation { Arabic = request.Description.Arabic, English = request.Description.English, Persian = request.Description.Persian },
            TranslationName = new Translation { Arabic = request.Name.Arabic, English = request.Name.English, Persian = request.Name.Persian },
            Duration = request.Duration
        };
        await _uow.GenericRepository<Package>().InsertOneAsync(package, null, cancellationToken);

        return package.Id;
    }
}
```

consumer in micro B

```
public class GetCurrencyByNameConsumer : IConsumer<GetCurrencyByNameRequest>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public GetCurrencyByNameConsumer(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<GetCurrencyByNameRequest> context)
    {
        // break point not hit
        var filter = Builders<Currency>.Filter.Eq(x => x.CurrencyName, new CurrencyName(context.Message.Name));
        var currency = await _uow.GenericRepository<Currency>()
            .GetSingleDocumentByFilterAsync(filter, context.CancellationToken);
        if (currency == null)
        {
            await context.RespondAsync(new GetCurrencyByNameResponse
            {
                Id = string.Empty,
                Name = string.Empty
            });
        }
        else
        {
            await context.RespondAsync(new GetCurrencyByNameResponse
            {
                Id = currency.Id,
                Name = currency.CurrencyName
            });
        }
    }
}
```

masstransit configuration in micro A

```
  services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            var entryAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName.Contains("Payment.Application"));
            x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
            x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(configuration["RabbitMqSettings:Host"], configuration["RabbitMqSettings:VirtualHost"], h =>
                {
                    h.Username(configuration["RabbitMqSettings:Username"]);
                    h.Password(configuration["RabbitMqSettings:Password"]);
                });
                cfg.UseDelayedRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
                cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));
                cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });
```

Massrtransit configuration in micro B

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            var entryAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName.Contains("Discount.Application"));
            x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
            x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(configuration["RabbitMqSettings:Host"], configuration["RabbitMqSettings:VirtualHost"], h =>
                {
                    h.Username(configuration["RabbitMqSettings:Username"]);
                    h.Password(configuration["RabbitMqSettings:Password"]);
                });
                cfg.UseDelayedRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
                cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));
                cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });
```

integration test in micro A

```
public async Task CreatePackageCommand_InsertToDb_ReturnPackage()
    {

        await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>()
            .AddMassTransitTestHarness(x =>
            {
                x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                x.AddHandler<GetCurrencyByNameRequest>(context =>
                    context.RespondAsync(new GetCurrencyByNameResponse
                    {
                        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString(),
                        Name = "Dollar"
                    }));
                x.AddRequestClient<GetCurrencyByNameResponse>();
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider(true);

        var harness = provider.GetTestHarness();

        await harness.Start();

        IRequestClient<GetCurrencyByNameRequest>? client = harness.GetRequestClient<GetCurrencyByNameRequest>();
        await Task.Delay(20000);
        var req = new GetCurrencyByNameRequest
        {
            Name = "Dollar"
        };
        var response = await client.GetResponse<GetCurrencyByNameResponse>(req);

        var command = new CreatePackageCommand
        {
            IsActive = true,
            Description = new Translation
            {
                Arabic = StringHelper.RandomString(10),
                English = StringHelper.RandomString(10),
                Persian = StringHelper.RandomString(10),
            },
            Sort = 1,
            Name = new Translation
            {
                Arabic = StringHelper.RandomString(10),
                English = StringHelper.RandomString(10),
                Persian = StringHelper.RandomString(10),
            },
            Price = 999,
            CurrencyName = "Dollar"
        };
        var packageId = await SendAsync(command);
        packageId.Should().NotBeNull();
        packageId.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    }
```

**Full error message:**

```
MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException : Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: cc190000-3e5f-84a9-eceb-08db90015de7
   at MassTransit.Clients.ClientRequestHandle`1.SendRequest()
   at MassTransit.Clients.ResponseHandlerConnectHandle`1.GetTask() in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/ResponseHandlerConnectHandle.cs:line 53
   at MassTransit.Clients.RequestClient`1.GetResponseInternal[T](SendRequestCallback request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestTimeout timeout, RequestPipeConfiguratorCallback`1 callback) in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/RequestClient.cs:line 195
   at Payment.Application.PackagesNutritionist.V1.Commands.CreatePackageNutritionist.CreatePackageCommandHandler.Handle(CreatePackageCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\O2fit\New o2fit2\o2fitBackend\src\Services\Payment\Payment.Application\PackagesNutritionist\V1\Commands\CreatePackageNutritionist\CreatePackageCommandHandler.cs:line 28
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Payment.Application.Common.Behaviours.PerformanceBehaviour`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\O2fit\New o2fit2\o2fitBackend\src\Services\Payment\Payment.Application\Common\Behaviours\PerformanceBehaviour.cs:line 21
   at Payment.Application.Common.Behaviours.ValidationBehaviour`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\O2fit\New o2fit2\o2fitBackend\src\Services\Payment\Payment.Application\Common\Behaviours\ValidationBehaviour.cs:line 31
   at Payment.Application.Common.Behaviours.UnhandledExceptionBehaviour`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\O2fit\New o2fit2\o2fitBackend\src\Services\Payment\Payment.Application\Common\Behaviours\UnhandledExceptionBehaviour.cs:line 16
   at Payment.IntegrationTests.Testing.SendAsync[TResponse](IRequest`1 request) in C:\O2fit\New o2fit2\o2fitBackend\tests\Services\Payment\IntegrationTests\Payment.IntegrationTests\Testing.cs:line 28
   at Payment.IntegrationTests.Commands.Command.CreatePackageCommandTests.CreatePackageCommand_InsertToDb_ReturnPackage() in C:\O2fit\New o2fit2\o2fitBackend\tests\Services\Payment\IntegrationTests\Payment.IntegrationTests\Commands\Command\CreatePackageCommandTests.cs:line 80
   at Payment.IntegrationTests.Commands.Command.CreatePackageCommandTests.CreatePackageCommand_InsertToDb_ReturnPackage() in C:\O2fit\New o2fit2\o2fitBackend\tests\Services\Payment\IntegrationTests\Payment.IntegrationTests\Commands\Command\CreatePackageCommandTests.cs:line 82
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.TaskAwaitAdapter.GenericAdapter`1.BlockUntilCompleted()
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.MessagePumpStrategy.NoMessagePumpStrategy.WaitForCompletion(AwaitAdapter awaiter)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Execution.SimpleWorkItem.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<PerformWork>b__0()
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.ContextUtils.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.<DoIsolated>b__0(Object _)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.ContextUtils.DoIsolated(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.ContextUtils.DoIsolated[T](Func`1 func)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Execution.SimpleWorkItem.PerformWork()



-----

One or more child tests had errors
  Exception doesn't have a stacktrace



10:29:12.858-I Configured endpoint get-currency-by-name-request, Consumer: MassTransit.DependencyInjection.MessageHandlerConsumer<EventBus.Messages.Contracts.Services.Discounts.Currencies.Query.GetCurrencyByName.GetCurrencyByNameRequest>
10:29:12.874-D Starting bus instances: IBus
10:29:12.875-D Starting bus: loopback://localhost/
10:29:12.897-D Endpoint Ready: loopback://localhost/DESKTOPU9A6PCU_ReSharperTestRunner_bus_3ocoyyb6m6nkuk7bbdp3yykogi
10:29:12.897-D Endpoint Ready: loopback://localhost/get-currency-by-name-request
10:29:12.900-I Bus started: loopback://localhost/
10:29:32.942-D Create send transport: loopback://localhost/urn:message:EventBus.Messages.Contracts.Services.Discounts.Currencies.Query.GetCurrencyByName:GetCurrencyByNameRequest
10:29:33.027-D SEND loopback://localhost/urn:message:EventBus.Messages.Contracts.Services.Discounts.Currencies.Query.GetCurrencyByName:GetCurrencyByNameRequest cc190000-3e5f-84a9-f99f-08db90015cce EventBus.Messages.Contracts.Services.Discounts.Currencies.Query.GetCurrencyByName.GetCurrencyByNameRequest
10:29:33.068-D Create send transport: loopback://localhost/DESKTOPU9A6PCU_ReSharperTestRunner_bus_3ocoyyb6m6nkuk7bbdp3yykogi
10:29:33.082-D SEND loopback://localhost/DESKTOPU9A6PCU_ReSharperTestRunner_bus_3ocoyyb6m6nkuk7bbdp3yykogi cc190000-3e5f-84a9-6cd9-08db90015ce1 EventBus.Messages.Contracts.Services.Discounts.Currencies.Query.GetCurrencyByName.GetCurrencyByNameResponse
10:29:33.088-D RECEIVE loopback://localhost/get-currency-by-name-request cc190000-3e5f-84a9-f99f-08db90015cce EventBus.Messages.Contracts.Services.Discounts.Currencies.Query.GetCurrencyByName.GetCurrencyByNameRequest MassTransit.DependencyInjection.MessageHandlerConsumer<EventBus.Messages.Contracts.Services.Discounts.Currencies.Query.GetCurrencyByName.GetCurrencyByNameRequest>(00:00:00.0339669)
10:29:33.090-D RECEIVE loopback://localhost/DESKTOPU9A6PCU_ReSharperTestRunner_bus_3ocoyyb6m6nkuk7bbdp3yykogi cc190000-3e5f-84a9-6cd9-08db90015ce1 EventBus.Messages.Contracts.Services.Discounts.Currencies.Query.GetCurrencyByName.GetCurrencyByNameResponse MassTransit.MessageHandler<EventBus.Messages.Contracts.Services.Discounts.Currencies.Query.GetCurrencyByName.GetCurrencyByNameResponse>(00:00:00.0006912)
10:30:04.821-D Stopping bus instances: IBus
10:30:04.823-D Stopping bus: loopback://localhost/
10:30:04.827-D Endpoint Stopping: loopback://localhost/get-currency-by-name-request
10:30:04.827-D Consumer Stopping: loopback://localhost/get-currency-by-name-request (Stop Receive Transport)
10:30:04.833-D Endpoint Completed: loopback://localhost/get-currency-by-name-request
10:30:04.834-D Consumer Completed: loopback://localhost/get-currency-by-name-request: 1 received, 1 concurrent
10:30:04.835-D Endpoint Stopping: loopback://localhost/DESKTOPU9A6PCU_ReSharperTestRunner_bus_3ocoyyb6m6nkuk7bbdp3yykogi
10:30:04.835-D Consumer Stopping: loopback://localhost/DESKTOPU9A6PCU_ReSharperTestRunner_bus_3ocoyyb6m6nkuk7bbdp3yykogi (Stop Receive Transport)
10:30:04.836-D Endpoint Completed: loopback://localhost/DESKTOPU9A6PCU_ReSharperTestRunner_bus_3ocoyyb6m6nkuk7bbdp3yykogi
10:30:04.836-D Consumer Completed: loopback://localhost/DESKTOPU9A6PCU_ReSharperTestRunner_bus_3ocoyyb6m6nkuk7bbdp3yykogi: 1 received, 1 concurrent
10:30:04.842-I Bus stopped: loopback://localhost/
```